# How can I use 'Edit2D' in mobile device

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge

I want to create shapes with 'polygonEditTool'(edit2.defaultTools.polygonTool).

Now,I have completed PC version.

But there is a problem in mobile device.

After I executing 'polygonEditTool',No matter how I touch screen ,it doesn't response.(connecting mouse can work)

```
export const startTool = (tool) => {
    // console.log(tool)

    const viewer = window.VIEWER;
    var controller = viewer.toolController;

    // Check if currently active tool is from Edit2D
    var activeTool = controller.getActiveTool();
    var isEdit2D = activeTool && activeTool.getName().startsWith("Edit2");

    // deactivate any previous edit2d tool
    if (isEdit2D) {
        console.log('isEdit2D')
        controller.deactivateTool(activeTool.getName());
        activeTool = null;
    }

    // stop editing tools
    if (!tool) {
        return;
    }

    controller.activateTool(tool.getName());

}

 window.VIEWER.loadExtension('Autodesk.Edit2D').then(edit2d => {
            const polyTool = edit2d.defaultTools.polygonTool
            startTool(polyTool)
        })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the `Autodesk.Edit2D` extension does not support touch-enabled devices.